# Javascript : Dar .hide em tudo que estiver aberto

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde. Gostaria de saber como fazer para ao invés de escrever:

```
  $("#removemirror3").click(function(){
  $("#mirror31").hide("slow");
  $("#mirror32").hide("slow");
  $("#mirror33").hide("slow");
  $("#add4mirror").hide("slow");
```

Escrever um hide geral que esconda tudo que estiver aberto.
Abraços.

Comment: Você pode fazer tudo em uma linha: `$("#mirror31, #mirror32, #mirror33, #add4mirror").hide("slow");`

Comment: E não tem um jeito que não tenha que escrever todos?

Comment: Adicionar classes aos elementos é um dos usos mais comuns. Você pode também deixar um container por fora dos elementos e esconder apenas o cantainer. Há várias formas de fazer isso, depende da criatividade...

Comment: renan e como eu faço para esconder toda a sequencia? dar um hide em foo[]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Guilherme, para tal você precisa de um elemento em comum entre todos os mirror. Por exemplo olhe o HTML abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mirror30" data-mirror class="hidden" ></div>
<div id="mirror31" data-mirror ></div>
<div id="mirror32" data-mirror ></div>
<div id="mirror33" data-mirror ></div>
<div id="mirror34" data-mirror class="hidden" ></div>
<div id="add4mirror" data-mirror ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

No caso acima, todos os mirror tem a propriedade data-mirror, então você pode usa-la para selecionar a todos eles.

Como você precisa apenas dos visiveis, você pode aplicar um filtro `:visible`

```
$("[data-mirror]:visible").hide("slow");
```

```js
var btHidden = $("#btHidden");
btHidden.click(function () {
  var visibleMirror = $("[data-mirror]:visible");
  visibleMirror.hide("slow");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }

.container {
  height: 120px;
}

.mirror {
  float: left;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="mirror30" data-mirror class="mirror hidden" ></div>
  <div id="mirror31" data-mirror class="mirror" ></div>
  <div id="mirror32" data-mirror class="mirror" ></div>
  <div id="mirror33" data-mirror class="mirror" ></div>
  <div id="mirror34" data-mirror class="mirror hidden" ></div>
  <div id="add4mirror" data-mirror class="mirror" ></div>
</div>
<button id="btHidden" >Esconder Tudo</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar um contexto para fazer a seleção dos elementos e dar um .hide()

Exemplo:

- Utilizar um seleção por classe em comum.
- Fazer a busca por atributo em específico.
- Utilizar o elemento pai e utilizar o .find por elementos.

Crie um contexto para melhorar a sua seleção de elementos, ai a manipulação ficará mais simples.

Answer (score 3):

É possível selecionar elementos que contenham parte do `id`. Vale ressaltar que existem outras maneiras mais fáceis de fazer esta manipulação, conforme mencionado nas outras rspostas, mais veja um exemplo:

```js
 $("button").click(function(){
     // seleciona todos os elementos que contenham mirror no id
     //$("[id*=mirror]").hide("slow"); 
     
     // seleciona todos os elementos que contenham mirror3 no id
     //$("[id*=mirror3]").hide("slow"); 
   
     // seleciona todos os elementos que contenham mirror3 no id, exceto botão
     $("[id*=mirror3]:not(button)").hide("slow"); 
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mirror31">#mirror31</div>
<div id="mirror32">#mirror32</div>
<div id="mirror33">#mirror33</div>
<div id="add4mirror">add4mirror</div>
<button type="button" id="removemirror3">Remove</button>
```